# How to transfer large data between pages in Perl/CGI?

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I have worked with CGI pages a lot and dealt with cookies and storing the data in the /tmp directory in Linux. 
Basically I am running a query for millions of records using SQL, and am saving it in a hash format. I want to transfer that data to Ajax ( which eventually will perform some calculation and return a graph using Google API.

Or, I want it to transfer that data to another CGI page somehow.

PS : The data I am talking about here is in forms of 10-100+ MB's.

Until now, i've been saving that data on the file in the server, but again, it's a hassle to deal with that data on the server for each query.

Comment: Could you show a bit more of your current or desired architecture?  If you could use the data in "another CGI page", why not just let that CGI page do the SQL query?  Unless you need the data to "persist" for another query or for some other process.  Also, I agree with w/ Jim Brandt's concern about 100MB being transferred to the browser.  If you have access to the data on the server and the server can do the Google API stuff, let it handle the big data.  Just transfer to the browser the info that the user needs to see and/or the AJAX hooks to let the browser fetch more data.

Comment: I am using the data coming from the DB in both the pages. I just want to know, what do expert programmers out there use to optimize the page load vs the large data sets transferred between 2 pages.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention why it's a hassle to deal with the data on the server for each query, but assuming the hassle is working with the file, [DBM::Deep](http://search.cpan.org/~sprout/DBM-Deep-2.0004/) might make it relatively easy to write the hash out and get it back again. Once you have that, you could create a simple script to return it as JSON and access it as needed from Javascript or other pages. Although I think the browser might slow down with 100MB JSON data structure.

Comment: It is a hassle, since for each user per query, I have to create a new file store the data, retrieve it, and then remove that file from the server.

Comment: I haven't checked out DBM::Deep, I agree, browser does slow down, but once it is in the broswer, I want the quickest way to use that data for different CGI pages. ( One load time wait is fine), but i was wondering the quickest way to use that same data between pages.

Comment: I think you will have consider some redesign of your pages, likely using an iframe (or frame) so you can have the root frame doing the initial query and store the structure.  Then the pages loaded into the iframe can access the object in the root structure, eliminating the need to request the data from the server itself.